# Copy the path of a file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, user-interface

I have located a file very deep in a folder structure in a Shared Drive in Google Drive (web interface). The file is in a location like this:

alpha > beta > gamma > delta > ... > kappa > fileImInterestedIn.txt

Is there any way how I can get this path as a text string and copy it so that I can paste it elsewhere? I have do do this again and again. Manually copying the path by typing is tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need a coded solution

You will **need** either a Google Apps Script, a 3rd party application, or a browser extension because the Drive web application doesn't include the functionality you want.

Though the web application may lack a feature you desire simply because of design decisions, Google makes available its [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk), which enables amateur and professional developers to access and extend Drive functionality using their own custom programs.

This can be as simple as writing your own [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/start) to retrieve the plain text path of file from Drive, or it could be a 3rd party developing an application with a more comprehensive set of tools.

Assuming you don't want to take on the daunting task of of coding your own solution, the alternative (and my recommendation) is to use a 3rd party solution that meets your needs.

#### Warning about 3rd Party Apps

You should always do your your own proper due dilligence prior to installing anything from a third party, whether an extension, an application, or a script.  I have included some of my observations related to Drive Explorer at the bottom of the post.

#### Suggested Application: Drive Explorer

After a quick review of some options, I am suggesting you install [Drive Explorer](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) which can be downloaded from the Google Workspace Marketplace.

I am not affiliated with [Drive Explorer](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) in any way, however it has a lot of Drive-related features including the ability to list file paths.

In the article [How to Get & Copy Path of Google Drive Files & Folders](https://www.syncwithtech.org/google-drive-file-path/) they explain how to accomplish what you want using [Drive Explorer](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513):

> 1. Right-click one or more files on your Google Drive.
> 2. Select Open with → Drive Explorer.
> 3. In the tab opened, select Fetch files and authorize Drive Explorer.
> 4. You will see the file path in one of the columns.
>    [image]

#### My Observations

A cursory examination of [Drive Explorer](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) resulted in the following observations:

1. The same [download URL](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) has existed since at least November 2020 when the Internet archive made [this first capture](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) (27 captures made in total).
2. In 2020 it had ~120,000 downloads, 221 user ratings averaging 4.5 stars (out of 5)
3. As of 06/14/2023 it has ~563,000 downloads, 502 user ratings averaging 4.6 stars (out of 5)
4. The [download page](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_explorer/520711270513) links to support resources

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround is opening a Google Colaboratory Python notebook. To open a Colab notebook, click "+New" on the top left of the Drive homepage then click "More" and click "Google Colaboratory", then mount your Google Drive:

Write these two lines in the first cell of the notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive;
drive.mount('/content/drive'); # This will prompt for authorization.
```

Then from the file explorer window on the left go to content (folders are arranged in alphabetical order) -> drive -> MyDrive -> .... -> the folder/file you want to get the path of.

Next right click on the three vertical dots which show up when you hover your mouse on the file/folder and click "Copy path". This will copy the path in the form of a string in your clipboard.

Then go to any cell of your Google Colaboratory notebook and paste to see that the file/folder path has indeed been copied correctly.

I use this technique often for working with data stored in different folders inside my Google Drive while working in Google Colab.

Comment: Awesome technique! I like it a lot because there is no need to rely on a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this lack of a simple feature would be to right click the file or folder of interest and select 'organize', then 'Add shortcut'. This would allow you to create a shortcut to the file that you can place in a location with a simpler file path (such as directly in the home folder of My Drive). You could then use the path to the shortcut, which would be shorter and easier to copy.